# loading icicle-mode in emacs on startup by default

Tags: emacs, icicles

I would like to configure emacs so that the Icy mode is active by default. As suggested in "icicles-doc1.el", I added the following code at the end of my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'icicles)
(icicle-mode 1)
```

When I run emacs, I get a *Warning* buffer:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/.emacs':
>
> File error: Cannot open load file, icicles
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
>   the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

When I do the debug option, a *Backtrace* buffer says something like:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "icicles") 
>   require(icicles)
>     eval-buffer(# nil "c:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" nil t)  ; 
>    Reading at buffer position 5062
>     load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" 
>    "c:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/.emacs" t t)
>     load("~/.emacs" t t)
>     #[0 "\205\262

With or without those two lines in my `.emacs` that are causing the problem, icicle-mode seems to work fine when I do a `M-x icicle-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(file-error "Cannot open load file" "icicles")` means that Emacs didn't know where to find library `icicles.el[c]`. You need to put the location of the **Icicles** files in variable `load-path`.

E.g, if your **Icicles** files are in directory `/my/icicles/` then you need to do this (e.g., in your init file, `~/.emacs`):

```
 (add-to-list 'load-path "/my/icicles/")
```

Do that before you do `(require 'icicles)`.  That way, Emacs will know where to load **Icicles** from.

Comment: I don't know why but this keep fails in emacs28 , the way I define the `load-path`: `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/icicles/")`

Comment: @alper: Are the Icicles files in that directory? Do you see the same problem if you start with `emacs -Q` (no init file) and you then do that? Do you see the same problem if you use an Emacs release (i.e., 27 or earlier)? Emacs 28 is not released - there are no doubt bugs that haven't yet been sorted out. But this sounds pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `(require 'icicles)` code is failing, but the <kbd>M-x icy-mode</kbd> is working, then it seems that someone has already set up your Emacs installation to include icicles via an `autoload` command, but didn't update the `load-path` to include the directory where `icicles.el` resides.

Replace those two lines with:

```
(icy-mode 1)
```

(which is the equivalent of <kbd>M-x icy-mode</kbd> when icicles has yet to be enabled)

If you want to use a *different* version of icicles, then you need to add the proper directory to the load path.

Comment: On double-checking I've realized that it's only "M-x icicle-mode" that works as soon as emacs loads. I actually have to do that first or else "M-x icy-mode" will give me '[No match]'

In any case, whether I put `(icy-mode 1)` or `(icicle-mode 1)` into my `.emacs`, with or without `(require 'icicles)`, I still seem to be getting the same original \*Warning* buffer.